# What does it mean to "assert a pin"?

Tags: xbee, terminology

From the XBee/XBeePro product manual page 24 ([link to pdf](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000982_G.pdf&ei=lOzNT8WfBY7Ssgbx1tTLCg&usg=AFQjCNGV-Q6daqj-vADFEdPmbtu_mC77hA&sig2=9Q6MudklQmVaSUzLsX43Ug)):

> Sleep Modes enable the RF module to enter states of low-power consumption when not in use. In order to enter Sleep Mode, one of the following conditions must be met (in addition to the module having a non-zero SM parameter value):
>
> - Sleep_RQ (pin 9) **is asserted** and the module is in a pin sleep mode (SM = 1, 2, or 5)
> - The module is idle (no data transmission or reception) for the amount of time defined by the
>   ST (Time before Sleep) parameter. [NOTE: ST is only active when SM = 4-5.]

What is meant by "asserting a pin"?

Answer (score 29):

*Asserting a pin* means setting it to its *active state*.

*De-asserting a pin* means setting it to its *inactive state*.

If a pin is *active high* (which it is, in your case), then asserting it means setting it to *logic high* (usually 3.3V/5V) and de-asserting it means setting it to a *logic low* (0V).

On the same page of the datasheet you've linked there's Table 2-04 which shows that Asserting pin 9 (Sleep_RQ) means setting it *high*:
[image]

Comment: One minor caveat: de-asserting a pin in some contexts may mean *driving* it to the state opposite the active state, or it may mean *floating* the pin, to allow the pin to return itself to the inactive state (and also possibly allowing other devices to assert the pin).

Comment: I think the word is used in a electronics in a different way than what the word originally meant. In common English "assert" means rougly: to state with confidence, to make sure smth is the case. In programming it means: check that an expression evaluates to true, otherwise throw exception.

Comment: @LucyBrennan I agree. It's used differently than in programming.

Comment: If you think of asserting *signals* (not pins), it's closer to English. To assert the `RESET#` signal makes more sense than to assert the `RESET#` pin (at least to me). It also avoids loaded words that might give the wrong idea if asserting `RESET#` involves driving it low (or not driving it high).

Answer (score 13):

It means that the **active level is applied**. In the manual active level is indicated between brackets ("high"). That's the common standard for GPIO (General Purpose I/O), but lots of signals are often active low, like \$\overline{\mathrm{CS}}\$ (Chip Select), \$\overline{\mathrm{OE}}\$ (Output Enable), \$\overline{\mathrm{UB}}\$ (Upper Byte). Asserting \$\overline{\mathrm{CS}}\$ means make that line low. (The overline indicates active low logic).

Answer (score 3):

To be a little bit more precise, (de)asserting a pin usually means that you must have a **transition** from one state to an other. From active to inactive if you de-assert the pin. From inactive to active if you assert it.

So, assuming you must assert (active high) a pin:

- either it is *currently low* (i.e.: inactive), you only have to *set it high* (i.e.: active),
- *but* if it is *already high*, you must first *set it low* in order to *set it high again* just after that.